# SHGetKnownFolderItem - fails on Wow64

Tags: c++, windows, api

I want to get a list of installed windows updates.

I compile 32 bit executable, and run it on a 64-bit machine (Windows 10)

I call the function SHGetKnownFolderItem to get the known folder of FOLDERID_AppUpdates, However, I get E_INVALIDARG

In x64 it works fine. I have limitation to compile it in 32-bit.

I chose that option because it was the fastest.

The code:

```
void ViewInstalledUpdates()
{
using namespace std;
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
int count = 0;

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    CComPtr<IShellItem> pUpdates;
    CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> pShellEnum;

    hr = SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_AppUpdates, static_cast<KNOWN_FOLDER_FLAG>(0), nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pUpdates));
    hr = pUpdates->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellEnum));
    if (pShellEnum)
    {
        do {
            CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
            CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> szName;

            hr = pShellEnum->Next(1, &pItem, nullptr);
            if (pItem)
            {
                HRESULT hres = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &szName);
                std::wcout << static_cast<LPWSTR>(szName) << endl;
                count++;
            }
        } while (hr == S_OK);
    }
}
CoUninitialize();
std::wcout << L"Found " << count << " updates" << endl;
return;
```

}

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A hollow voice whispered: "64 bit child process".

In all seriousness, what you have here is trying to make an OS maintenance tool without matching the tool to the OS. Don't do it man. Match the tool bitness to the OS bitness no matter what.

There ain't no rule that 32 bit processes can't start 64 bit processes.